# Auto-adding to a Collection when using a Send-to-Kindle email

Tags: kindle, kindle-paperwhite, send-to-kindle, collections

When sending an ebook to the @kindle.com email ID to add to your Amazon "personal documents", is it possible to specify a Collection-name somewhere in the email such that the book automatically goes into the collection when it reaches the device?

I vaguely remember reading some degree of control using the email subject/body, but am not sure what exactly customized using that - book's title? Author? Collections? If there's an Amazon help page about this that I've missed, a link would be highly appreciated too.

Answer (score 2):

Only thing you can control via email subject is whether to use Amazon's convert feature

From https://www.amazon.com/sendtokindle/email

> PDFs can be converted to the Kindle format so you can take advantage of functionality such as variable font size, annotations, and Whispersync. To have a document converted to Kindle format, the subject line should be "convert" when e-mailing a personal document to your Send-to-Kindle address.

Answer (score 0):

No.

It will show in `amazon.com/myk` under "docs".  You can select multiple items to organize into collections.

Perhaps there was such an option in the past.