# Send to kindle - store in specific folder

Tags: kindle, send-to-kindle

When using "send to kindle" feature (e.g. through [Readability](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/readability/oknpjjbmpnndlpmnhmekjpocelpnlfdi)), is there any way to put the files on Kindle into some folder, not into main directory?

Usually I send some articles to read them later, but then they end up in main folder and there's a big mess. If they could be stored under some folder, e.g. "articles" that would be much cleaner. Any way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent in Kindle to folders is collections. Usually you can create this on the ebook reader yourself.

This Kindle help document https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201733490 indicates that there is a cloud component to collections on later devices, but I don't know what this means for kindle apps.

For the Android Kindle app's main screen, when you keep holding down on the ebook title,a  **+** option will appear  which allows you to add to collections.

**UPDATE:** https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201715640 "Note: Collections created on devices or apps that support Cloud Collections cannot be imported to devices and apps that do not support Cloud Collections. Any existing collections you’ve created on non-supported devices will not change and will not be available in the Cloud."

Comment: Yes I know about collections, though the question is similar - is there a way to automatically add to specific collection? [There's already a question](http://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/5957/auto-adding-to-a-collection-when-using-a-send-to-kindle-email) on that, but without answer... so I did not include this part into question.

And as adding to collection is more important - for grouping files "logically", I'd also like to keep files and folders clean "physically".

Comment: This link might help https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201715640 . I'm guessing the interface issue is that when something is stored in collections it also appears on your home screen.

Comment: Thanks, though it says about managing collections online, not mentioning either how to store sent file in specific folder or add to collection automatically...

Comment: calibre supports putting into a particular folder, is there similar functionality by mail?